# Is it possible to convert any type (Url) to base64 format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, base64

I have a link, which can return any type of file (say image/jpeg, zip, mp4 etc).

Now i want to convert the above mentioned file data into base64.

Is it possible with javascript alone ?

I tried canvas.toDataUrl(), but that can help only if my returning file format is image.

Comment: You get the file contents via `XMLHttpRequest` or you want the server output to be converted to base64 for viewing it in your browser?

Comment: I want the file content to be converted into base64 in xmlhttpRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    //the file has been loaded as responseText in xhr
    alert(btoa(this.responseText));
  }
}

//download video file
xhr.open("someVideo.mpg", "get", true);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, while trying to btoa(), i am getting the following error.

Comment: Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Comment: This may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.btoa#Unicode_Strings

Comment: I used the following code, but my image file is getting broken